# Yesod conditional subsite

Tags: haskell, yesod

I want to create a part of my Yesod website that should be enabled only if certain configuration settings are present. So I have something like this (omitting details):

```
data MasterData = MasterData
  { subData :: Maybe SubData
  }

data SubData = SubData { ... }

mkYesodData "SubData" [parseRoutes| ... |]

mkYesodData "MasterData" [parseRoutes|
  /sub SubsiteR SubData getSubData
|]
```

How could I make my site return HTTP 404 for all urls starting with `/sub` if `subData` is `Nothing`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach would be to create a newtype wrapper around `Maybe` that provides an instance of [YesodSubDispatch](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.4.2/20130829-168/yesod-core/Yesod-Core.html#t:YesodSubDispatch), and have it return 404 whenever its argument is `Nothing`.

This turned out to be a fun exercise in subsites; you can [view the code as a Gist](https://gist.github.com/snoyberg/8d85d41c5b4d0da002ae). The one trick is that, when you link to that subsite, you'll need to wrap your constructors with `OptionalRoute`.